# C# Dispatcher Invoke and normal code execution order

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, invoke

I have some doubts on how `Dispatcher.Invoke` exactly works. It more of a theoretical question (I don't have any code written in this way).

Let's suppose I have this code:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => func1() );
func2();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => func3() );
func4();
```

From what I have understood, `func1()` is guaranteed to be executed before `func3()`. (and `func2()` before `func4()`).
But what is the relation between the invoked functions (1 and 3) and the normal functions (2 and 4)?

Since the invoked functions are executed on their thread, I suppose that there is not really a relation: for example, `func1()` might be executed before or after `func2()`, depending on the thread availability.
But I suppose `func3()` will be executed always after `func2()`, since it is started after it.
I also think that some functions might have overlapped execution, being on different threads.

Is this correct? Or I understood something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke#remarks):

> `Invoke` is a synchronous operation; therefore, control will not return to the calling object until after the callback returns.

So the `func1()`, `func2()`, `func3()` and `func4()` methods in your example will be invoked in exactly this order, sequentially and without overlap.